# Python AWS lambda JSON serialization issue

Tags: json, python-2.7, aws-lambda

I am currently writing the aws lambda function with python to http post requests
apprantly its failing to serialize json headers 
here my mode

```
  import json
  from botocore.vendored import requests

  API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.someservices.com/v1/aws_accounts"
  API_KEY = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"
  externalID ="dadsfasdfasdfasd"

  def api_post(account_id, rolearn, account_name):
      headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json", "api_key" : API_KEY}
      data = {"name":account_name,"authentication":{"protocol": "assume_role","assume_role_arn":rolearn,"assume_role_external_id":externalID}}
      json_data = json.dumps(data)
      response = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT,headers=headers, data=json_data)
      print(response)
      return response
```

this is the error I am getting 
      def lambda_handler(event, context):
          result = update_ch(event['account_id'],event['rolearn'],event['account_name'])
          return result

> raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
>   TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

Comment: please print your 'o' output and type i think it will help you also print type of json_data in log.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been sorted out . I was using wrong library